# Entity Framework MinLength doesn't working

Tags: asp.net, entity-framework, data-annotations

I have simple model of Courses and I want to achieve so that the property has a defined minimum string length. When entering a value less than 5, it should throw an exception, exactly as it is for the `required` attribute.

```
public class Course
    {
        [Key]
        public int Id { get; set; }

        [Required, MinLength(5)]
        public string Name { get; set; }

        public string PhotoUrl { get; set; }

        [Required]
        public int Capacity { get; set; }
    }
```

But even after migration added, I don't see in DbContextSnapshot minimum length on property `name` applied:

```
b.Property<string>("Name")
   .IsRequired()
   .HasColumnType("TEXT");
```

And when I try to add a Course with a name of 3 characters, everything ends well without exception throwed.

Comment: There's no such thing as a minimum length for EF, that's an MVC thing. `MaxLength` will work fine because that defines the column type. So a max length of 10 would make the column a `NVARCHAR(10)`.

Comment: @DavidG What do you mean? How can I validate a minum length for model property then?

Comment: I mean... ok it is not validate via database. But somehow this attribute has to work. It has to proc when trying to apply dbcontext savechanges, isn't it?

Comment: https://www.tektutorialshub.com/entity-framework/ef-data-annotations-stringlength-attribute/